# Why is the N side thinner than the P side in a photodiode?

Tags: diodes, semiconductors, photodiode, pn-junction

I have been reading that a photodiode is built by sandwiching a very thin N type semiconductor togther with a thicker P type. Why is that so?

Comment: I suspect a significant point has been missed. The backside layer of a planar photodiode is thin because the diffusion time for carriers generated outside the depletion region are *really* slow. Like three orders of magnitude *slower* than when generated in the depletion region. With speed being is part of almost product goal, this slower diffusion mechanism has to be mitigated! This is either done by a thinner backside layer or else an intrinsic layer, in between (PIN diode.)

Answer (score 6):

The texbook photo:

[image]

doesn't represent the **real** physical situation. I mean the actual sizes of the layers in relation to oneanother.

It is a **simplified view** that helps to explain what is happening in a [PN junction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%E2%80%93n_junction).

This is a more realistic presentation:

[image]

[found here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Typical-construction-of-a-photodiode-as-seen-from-the-side-in-cross-section-Reproduced_fig1_234983497)

This is another more realistic sideview drawing:

[image]

[found here](https://www.brainkart.com/article/Optical-Detectors_13629/)

The reason why the N-type layer is much thinner than the P-type layer is due to the fact that the manufacturing starts with a P-type wafer.

N-type doping is then implanted into that P-type wafer which will turn **a thin surface area** of that P-type wafer into N-type.

In these drawings the P-type layer is much thinner than the N-type so the opposite of what you stated (N-type is thinner). Actually that doesn't matter, the manufacturer starts with the **thick** layer and then add doping to make the **thin** layer.

If you start with a P-type wafer, after adding N-type doping you will get a thin N-type layer.

If you start with a N-type wafer, after adding P-type doping you will get a thin P-type layer.

*But it was P-type? Where did the all the P go?*

Good question! If the doping of the N-type is **higher** than than the existing doping of the P-type it will **overrule** that doping. The P-doping is still there but "overwhelmed" by the N-type, making the surface N-type.

Answer (score 1):

I’ll answer your 2nd question.

The battery is used here to reverse bias the PD for lower leakage current and lower junction capacitance. Then the voltage across the bias R to gnd. measures the current.

Others make prefer to use 0V bias and measure the conduction voltage with different characteristics. This is more sensitive but also more non-linear impedance for large variations.